# tf.hessians(f, x): not the same value as tf.gradients(tf.gradients(f, x), x) for an isolated, single variable?

Tags: tensorflow, mathematical-optimization, gradient-descent, derivative

So I have a `tf.Variable()` named `W` that is of `shape=[1]`.

I get that the `tf.hessians(loss, W)` isn't equal to the `tf.gradients(tf.gradients(loss, W), W)`, despite it should be the same thing: a second order derivative.

Here is a small gist for the code where I get the issue if I try to replace the Hessians by the double gradients:
https://gist.github.com/guillaume-chevalier/6b01c4e43a123abf8db69fa97532993f
Yet I observe that results do not converge if I use double gradients.

Answer (score -1):

Double gradient is called Laplacian: [Laplace Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator). It is taking derivative w.r.t the same x variable twice. However, Hessian matrix is taking derivative w.r.t combination of two x variables: [Hessian Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix). Thus the trace of Hessian would be Laplacian, which is double gradient.